# How to create Scripting Engine Like Console in Chrome or Firefox for a c# application with correct pattern

Tags: c#

i want to create a console with intellisense for my existing application, so i can run c# scripts inside it, which will affect my application in run time (maybe async methods), what design pattern is used for this kind of job which will be good with dependency injection, so i can inject it to all of my application? 
i mean like running this command :

```
open_menu();
```

and it goes inside application injects menu dependencies and shows it with outputing results.
how can i create this engine in c#? i prefer a wpf method but does no matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its good and detailed solved my problem https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2790/C-Script-Engine-tutorial